# Override vendor module (module-quote) Model file Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I want to override module-quote module.
I want to override file Model/QuoteManagment.php having function protected submitQuote

I did the same using preference. Steps I followed:

1. Created a custom module
2. Created ect/di.xml file

   ```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement" type="QuoteTracker\Module\Model\QuoteManagement" />
   ```
3. Created module.xml file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="QuoteTracker_Module" setup_version="1.0.2" />
     <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>>
        </sequence>
    </config>
    </config>
   ```
4. Created Model/QuoteManagement.php file which I want to override to write logs

   ```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    namespace QuoteTracker\Module\Model;

    use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement as MagentoQuoteManagement;
    use Magento\Authorization\Model\UserContextInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrder as ToOrderConverter;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\ToOrderAddress as ToOrderAddressConverter;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote as QuoteEntity;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem as ToOrderItemConverter;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment\ToOrderPayment as ToOrderPaymentConverter;
    use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterfaceFactory as OrderFactory;
    use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface as OrderManagement;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

    /**
     * Class QuoteManagement
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
     */
    //class QuoteManagement implements \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface
    class QuoteManagement extends MagentoQuoteManagement
    {
        /**
         * @var EventManager
         */
        protected $eventManager;

        /**
         * @var SubmitQuoteValidator
         */
        private $submitQuoteValidator;

        /**
         * @var OrderFactory
         */
        protected $orderFactory;

        /**
         * @var OrderManagement
         */
        protected $orderManagement;

        /**
         * @var CustomerManagement
         */
        protected $customerManagement;

        /**
         * @var ToOrderConverter
         */
        protected $quoteAddressToOrder;

        /**
         * @var ToOrderAddressConverter
         */
        protected $quoteAddressToOrderAddress;

        /**
         * @var ToOrderItemConverter
         */
        protected $quoteItemToOrderItem;

        /**
         * @var ToOrderPaymentConverter
         */
        protected $quotePaymentToOrderPayment;

        /**
         * @var UserContextInterface
         */
        protected $userContext;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
         */
        protected $quoteRepository;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
         */
        protected $customerRepository;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
         */
        protected $customerModelFactory;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\AddressFactory
         */
        protected $quoteAddressFactory;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
         */
        protected $dataObjectHelper;

        /**
         * @var StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $storeManager;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
         */
        protected $checkoutSession;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
         */
        protected $customerSession;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
         */
        protected $accountManagement;

        /**
         * @var QuoteFactory
         */
        protected $quoteFactory;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory
         */
        private $quoteIdMaskFactory;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
         */
        private $addressRepository;

        /**
         * @var array
         */
        private $addressesToSync = [];

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
         */
        private $request;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress
         */
        private $remoteAddress;

        /**
         * @param EventManager $eventManager
         * @param SubmitQuoteValidator $submitQuoteValidator
         * @param OrderFactory $orderFactory
         * @param OrderManagement $orderManagement
         * @param CustomerManagement $customerManagement
         * @param ToOrderConverter $quoteAddressToOrder
         * @param ToOrderAddressConverter $quoteAddressToOrderAddress
         * @param ToOrderItemConverter $quoteItemToOrderItem
         * @param ToOrderPaymentConverter $quotePaymentToOrderPayment
         * @param UserContextInterface $userContext
         * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
         * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
         * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerModelFactory
         * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\AddressFactory $quoteAddressFactory
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
         * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
         * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
         * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement
         * @param QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
         * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory|null $quoteIdMaskFactory
         * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface|null $addressRepository
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface|null $request
         * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
        */
        public function __construct(
            EventManager $eventManager,
            SubmitQuoteValidator $submitQuoteValidator,
            OrderFactory $orderFactory,
            OrderManagement $orderManagement,
            CustomerManagement $customerManagement,
            ToOrderConverter $quoteAddressToOrder,
            ToOrderAddressConverter $quoteAddressToOrderAddress,
            ToOrderItemConverter $quoteItemToOrderItem,
            ToOrderPaymentConverter $quotePaymentToOrderPayment,
            UserContextInterface $userContext,
            \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerModelFactory,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\AddressFactory $quoteAddressFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
            StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory = null,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository = null,
            \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request = null,
            \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress $remoteAddress = null
        ) {
            $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
            $this->submitQuoteValidator = $submitQuoteValidator;
            $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
            $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
            $this->customerManagement = $customerManagement;
            $this->quoteAddressToOrder = $quoteAddressToOrder;
            $this->quoteAddressToOrderAddress = $quoteAddressToOrderAddress;
            $this->quoteItemToOrderItem = $quoteItemToOrderItem;
            $this->quotePaymentToOrderPayment = $quotePaymentToOrderPayment;
            $this->userContext = $userContext;
            $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
            $this->customerModelFactory = $customerModelFactory;
            $this->quoteAddressFactory = $quoteAddressFactory;
            $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
            $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
            $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
            $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory::class);
            $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface::class);
            $this->request = $request ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface::class);
            $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
                ->get(\Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress::class);
        }

        /**
         * Submit quote
         *
         * @param Quote $quote
         * @param array $orderData
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel|\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface|object
         * @throws \Exception
         * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
         */
        protected function submitQuote(QuoteEntity $quote, $orderData = [])
        {
            $order = $this->orderFactory->create();
            $this->submitQuoteValidator->validateQuote($quote);
            if (!$quote->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
                if ($quote->getCustomerId()) {
                    $this->_prepareCustomerQuote($quote);
                    $this->customerManagement->validateAddresses($quote);
                }
                $this->customerManagement->populateCustomerInfo($quote);
            }
            $addresses = [];
            $quote->reserveOrderId();
            if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
                $this->dataObjectHelper->mergeDataObjects(
                    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::class,
                    $order,
                    $this->quoteAddressToOrder->convert($quote->getBillingAddress(), $orderData)
                );
            } else {
                $this->dataObjectHelper->mergeDataObjects(
                    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::class,
                    $order,
                    $this->quoteAddressToOrder->convert($quote->getShippingAddress(), $orderData)
                );
                $shippingAddress = $this->quoteAddressToOrderAddress->convert(
                    $quote->getShippingAddress(),
                    [
                        'address_type' => 'shipping',
                        'email' => $quote->getCustomerEmail()
                    ]
                );
                $shippingAddress->setData('quote_address_id', $quote->getShippingAddress()->getId());
                $addresses[] = $shippingAddress;
                $order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress);
                $order->setShippingMethod($quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod());
            }
            $billingAddress = $this->quoteAddressToOrderAddress->convert(
                $quote->getBillingAddress(),
                [
                    'address_type' => 'billing',
                    'email' => $quote->getCustomerEmail()
                ]
            );
            $billingAddress->setData('quote_address_id', $quote->getBillingAddress()->getId());
            $addresses[] = $billingAddress;
            $order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);
            $order->setAddresses($addresses);
            $order->setPayment($this->quotePaymentToOrderPayment->convert($quote->getPayment()));
            $order->setItems($this->resolveItems($quote));
            if ($quote->getCustomer()) {
                $order->setCustomerId($quote->getCustomer()->getId());
            }
            $order->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
            $order->setCustomerEmail($quote->getCustomerEmail());
            $order->setCustomerFirstname($quote->getCustomerFirstname());
            $order->setCustomerMiddlename($quote->getCustomerMiddlename());
            $order->setCustomerLastname($quote->getCustomerLastname());
            $this->submitQuoteValidator->validateOrder($order);

            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'sales_model_service_quote_submit_before',
                [
                    'order' => $order,
                    'quote' => $quote
                ]
            );

            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/order-tracker.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);

            try {
                $order = $this->orderManagement->place($order);

                $logger->info("Order placed sucessfully. - Order #".$order->getIncrementId());
                $logger->info(json_encode($order->getData()));

                $quote->setIsActive(false);
                $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                    'sales_model_service_quote_submit_success',
                    [
                        'order' => $order,
                        'quote' => $quote
                    ]
                );
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->rollbackAddresses($quote, $order, $e);

                $logger->info("Order placed unsucessfully. - Order #".$order->getIncrementId());
                $logger->info($e->getMessage());

                throw $e;
            }
            return $order;
        }
    }
   ```

While running setup:di:compile I am getting errors for multiple dependency files that are being called in this function. Please share the way to override this model file.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your module.xml file to this and try again:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="QuoteTracker_Module" setup_version="1.0.2">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```